# how can I collect values from entries that I displayed using a loop in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display an empty table so the user can fill it.
I used a loop to display entries to form a table. the problem is I want to get a list of the values in the table but the list that returns is filled with null values since it collects the data before displaying the table . I used a class Tbl to form the frame that contains the table and a method createTable in the frame class(page class).
ps. I get The dimensions from entries in another page.

```
class Tbl(tk.Frame):
       def __init__(self,root= None):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
            self.grid()
            self.list=self.create_widgets()
            
       def create_widgets(self):
                self.et = {}
                mat=[]
                con=0
                for i in range(t+1):
                 for j in range(m+1):
                    if (i==0):
                        if (j==0):
                            self.el = tk.Label(self, text=" ")
                            self.el.grid(row=i, column=j)
                        else :
                            self.el = tk.Label(self, text="M"+str(j),width=5,borderwidth=1, relief="solid",font=('Arial',14,'bold'),justify="center")
                            self.el.grid(row=i, column=j)
                    else :
                        if (j==0):
                            self.el = tk.Label(self, text="T"+str(i),width=5,borderwidth=1, relief="solid",font=('Arial',14,'bold'),justify="center")
                            self.el.grid(row=i, column=j)
                        else : 
                            self.et[con] = tk.Entry(self, width=5,borderwidth=1, relief="solid" ,fg='black',font=('Arial',16,'bold'),justify="center")
                            self.et[con].grid(row=i, column=j)
                            mat.append(self.et[con].get())
                            con +=1
                return mat
```

```
    def createTable(self):
        global t
        global m
        
        t=int(self.controller.tNb)
        m=int(self.controller.mNb)
        global tabl
        tabl=Tbl(self)
        tabl.place(relx=0.3,y=150)
```

I tried to use textvariables but It didn't work.

Comment: Your code does `for i in range(t+1)` and `for j in range(m+1):` but you haven't defined `t` or `m`, so this code won't run.

Comment: I get t and m from another class and they are well defined. The code runs but it returns a list of empty strings

Comment: The code _here_ will not run. Your example needs to be runnable.

Comment: I don't know how to give a runnable example since the my code is for 3 tkinter pages.(sorry this is the first tile I post a qst. still new to this. Thank you for responding)

Comment: You get the contents of those entry boxes just after they are created, so what you get will be all empty strings.

Comment: I tried to get them using a method but it didn't work .       def getMat(self):
           mtrx=[]
           for k in range(con):
                    mtrx.append(et[k].get())
           return mtrx

Comment: _"I don't know how to give a runnable example"_ all you have to do is put all of that code in one block, define `m` and `t`, and then create enough code to create an instance of your table. I think I added maybe 7 or 8 lines of code, which should be something you're responsible for doing.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. I hope I didn't take much of your time. Im new to software so It didn't work out for me when I tried structuring a runnable code. Hope you can understand and thank you again for your  your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over your dictionary of entries, getting the value of each by calling `get`. For example:

```
class Tbl(tk.Frame):
    ...
    def get(self):
        for key, item in self.et.items():
            print(f"{key} = {item.get()}")
```

It might be more intuitive to use a tuple of the form `(m,t)` when storing the items to `self.et`, assuming you need those values when using the data.

```
def create_widgets(self):
    ...
    self.et[(i,j)] = tk.Entry(...)
    ...
```

When you do that, the output of the `get` method defined above would look something like this when calling `table.get()` with `t` set to 2 and `m` set to 3:

```
root = tk.Tk()
table = Tbl(root)
button = tk.Button(root, command=table.get, text="Get")
...
```

```
(1, 1) = a
(1, 2) = b
(1, 3) = c
(2, 1) = d
(2, 2) = e
(2, 3) = f
```

Comment: I don't need to save the data with the keys. How can I write def get to insert the items in a list?

Comment: @User124: I recommend you read up on list comprehensions. It would probably be easiest to start by saving the entries in a list of lists rather than a dictionary or flat list.